# U substitution to turn a double integral into a convolution?

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution, substitution

I'm trying to work through the results of a classic paper in super-resolution microscopy (C. Sheppard, *Optik*, 1988). The main result sort of hinges on writing the double integral:

$$ \int dx \int dx^\prime h_{1}{(x^\prime)}t{(x^\prime - x_{s} - \frac{x}{2})}h_{2}{(x^\prime - x)} $$

into a convolution form:

$$ \{ h_{1}{(2x_{s})} \ast h_{2}{(2x_{s})} \} \ast t{(x_{s})} $$

I'm sure it's just a matter of simple u-substitution, but I'm stuck trying to find it.

Comment: What are the bounds? Are they taken to just be all real numbers?

Comment: Not specified in the paper, but likely it's meant to be $-\infty $ to $\infty $, real numbers.